# How can we write $r$ in polar coordinate as follows?

Tags: polar-coordinates

How can we write $r$ in polar coordinate as follows if it is $r=\lvert r_1-r_2\rvert$
$$(r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1r_2\cos\theta)^{1/2}$$

Comment: It follows from the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: @Azif00  OMG! really thanks